# What happens to the potentially inaccurate digits in floating point arithmetic?

Tags: floating-point, precision

According to Wikipedia, floating point arithmetic using [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is accurate up to a minimum of 15 digits.

I'm currently in the process of reading:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

But I'm still a bit confused on how exactly the digits past the 15th are handled. From what I understand sometimes they can be accurate and sometimes they are not.

An example:

```
           15th digit
                ^  
0.111222333444555xx..
```

**Due to the potential inaccuracy, it makes sense to me that these digits would just be ignored. If that's not the case then how are they handled?**

Comment: first off it is binary not decimal, the decimal comment is just a rough estimate.  what happens is they simply fall off the end.  Just like scientific notation, even if you have more digits you discard them.  with float you can choose to round or not round the bits as they fall off the end of the mantissa.

Comment: @dwelch What exactly is binary and not decimal? Are you saying that it's 15 "binary" digits?

Comment: the decimal value 123 is represented in binary as 1111011 for example.  it makes no sense to talk about a three digit decimal number when talking about computers.   google for the floating point format single, double, ect.  wikipedia shows the format.  there is a fixed number of bits in the mantissa, binary.  you can get a rough estimate of the decimal representation, but because the bases are different they dont really translate.

Comment: you can have a number that is exactly represented in binary, but when you show the decimal representation it may not be able to be represented or may take many digits.  likewise I think 0.1 cannot be accurately represented in floating point.   just like 1/3 cannot be represented in decimal (without an infinite number of digits).   just basic math stuff.

Comment: ahh, I see you did find the wikipedia article on double.  it shows you that the mantissa is fixed in size.

Comment: @dwelch I think I understand what you're getting at but just to clarify, there will still be a "minimum" of 15 (decimal) digits that are accurate? But anything after the total number of accurate binary digits does not matter (which can't always be a decimal number because it may not translate properly)?

Comment: you cannot relate the number of decimal digits directly to floating point.  without using vague words like minimum.   number of decimal digits is not really relevant to floating point.  the size of the exponent and mantissa and presense of sticky bits are all that are relevant

Comment: @dwelch Thank you, that makes sense.